# How do I make a button that makes text fade in and out?

Tags: css

I need a code that makes text fade in and out upon clicking a button with CSS/HTML. Could anyone help? It'd be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color:#000080;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #191970}

.button:active {
  background-color: #000080;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="button"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically to resume, I want text to fade in when the button is clicked. I'm not sure how, where or what to type to make it work. All I could figure out was the button.

Comment: Hello, 
you should read the rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, this is not how you ask a question here. You should provide your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question is *off-topic* here because SO is not a code-on-demand service. Please take the Tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour for a better understanding of this site.

Comment: Sorry about that. Ill update it

Comment: You need to provide your attempt at trying to resolve the issue.  Take a look at the following link for improving your question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jQuery

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Okay, but I don't know where to put it, or customize the text that needs to enter.

Comment: you don't know where to put the code? it's JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `focus` on the button and update the opacity (or any other property) like this:

```css
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000080;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  color: #000080;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #191970;
}

.button:focus {
  background-color: #000080;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

p {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:focus~p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
<p>
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p>
```

Comment: Okay, so I'm using [here](https://pastebin.com/3QZqUCWm) (It was too long to paste here), but it shows up blank... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SunTanLotion pau attention that the text should be placed exactly after the button Am using `~` as selector which means next element

Comment: Okay I got it, now, is there a way to disable it? Like close the text box?

Comment: @SunTanLotion yes you can for example use height property you make it `height:0;overflow:hidden` and then `height:auto`